# RSpec no route matches - missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, routes

I have a spec that is failing due to no route matches, here is the pertinent code:

```
describe AdminController do
  before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @admin = create(:admin)
    @user = create(:user)
    sign_in @admin, scope: :user
  end

  context "with admin user" do
    describe "DELETE #destroy" do
      it "deletes the contact" do
        puts @user.inspect
        expect{
          delete admin_destroy_user_path, id: @user.id
        }.to change(Profile, :count).by(-1)
      end
```

Error:

```
 AdminController with admin user DELETE #destroy deletes the contact
   Failure/Error: delete admin_destroy_user_path, id: @user.id

 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin"} missing    required keys: [:id]
```

Route:

```
admin_destroy_user DELETE /admin/:id(.:format)                              admin#destroy
```

I am not sure what I am missing, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of RSpec are you using? You likely need to pass the id like this: `delete admin_destroy_user_path, params: { id: @user.id }` assuming that `@user.id` actually returns a value.

Comment: Or you can use `admin_destroy_user_path(@user.id)`

Comment: Thank you gentlemen, but neither of these work, I get the same error using the params: option. and if I use Igor's option I get "ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/admin/2", :controller=>"admin"}"  Also I am using version 3.5.4 of RSpec.

Comment: Have you tried: `admin_destroy_user_path(id: @user.id)` ?

Comment: Thanks Taryn, I worked around the issue by installing Rails Admin.  Now I can do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help, I ended up refactoring to use Rails Admin instead.

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow, you should use the parentheses to pass the id to the route:

```
delete admin_destroy_user_path(id: @user.id)
```